# UI кнопки Unity, как сделать активной-неактивной

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в Unity из скрипта  перевести кнопку в состояние Disabled? Когда делаю вот так

```
 public GameObject lvl1;
 lvl1.SetActive(false);
```

Кнопка просто исчезает. 
А нужно чтобы вызывалось состояние, к которому прикреплены картинки в Button Script(sprite swap) (Highlighted sprite, pressed sprite, disabled sprite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в доках Юнити написано

```
    public Button startButton;
    public bool playersReady;


    void Update()
    {
        // checks if the players are ready and if the start button is useable
        if (playersReady == true && startButton.interactable == false)
        {
            //allows the start button to be used
            startButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }
```

Но так как вы, как и я, кнопку добавляете как GameObject, то здесь нужно идти вглубь. Брать компонент у объекта и через него отключать кнопку.

```
 public GameObject lvl1;
 lvl1.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать свойство кнопки [interactable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html).

Или отключить скрипт на кнопке. Или в самом скрипте прописать поведение.

> Кнопка просто исчезает.

В состоянии [Disabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) Перестают вызываться функции типа Update и тд, Все вложенные объекты, также становятся не активными.

> Making a GameObject inactive will disable every component, turning off any attached renderers, colliders, rigidbodies, scripts, etc... Any scripts that you have attached to the GameObject will no longer have Update() called

Comment: Добавлю
Данное свойство появляется если обращаться к кнопке как к UI.Button а не как к GameObject. Работает.